# How to run and configure java maven project in MuleSoft Anypoint Studio?

Tags: java, maven, rest-assured, mulesoft, anypoint-studio

I have created a java maven project in eclipse to get response from web services using rest api, but not able to get the response in Anypoint Studio using the same code I am getting error like importing of rest assured and many more. Could anyone help how to run same maven project that i have created in eclipse in MuleSoft Anypoint Studio to get the response. Please let me know if any further information required.

Comment: The correct name of the product is Anypoint Studio.

Comment: Hi Manu, welcome to Stack overflow. If you provide specific errors you have with enough information to analyze them, I believe, you chances to get help will be much higher

Answer (score 1):

Anypoint Studio only supports Mule projects.

Since it is based on Eclipse You might be able to install the Eclipse plugin for Java to add support for Java projects.

Comment: Installed eclipse marketplace in Anypoint studio but not helpful

Comment: Actually I see Java projects in the menu. Have you tried importing the project from the Eclipse worskpace (Import / General / Existing projects into workspace)?

Comment: Actually I need to import the project in Anypoint studio.. I have created the project in eclipse.. I have imported the project in Anypoint studio but i am getting errors in all class regarding the imports of restassured and java. Io imports..

Comment: Then your question should benmore specific and provide details of errors, dependencies used (what's rest assured exactly?) and the pom.